# How to save results using in array

Tags: python

how do I store results using an array i dont have much code to show but what I want is how do I store the print result using an array with for loop and global variables to add them up.

```
perimeter = 100
Tarea = 50
Infarea = 75

#Store Results
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    print('Perimeter =',perimeter, file=f)
    print('TotalArea = ',Tarea, file=f)
    print('Infected Area =',Infarea, file=f)
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for A2A,

So you are talking about array i.e. list.
You can do this as follows :

```
arr =[ ]
perimeter = 68.4
area = 573.3
radius = 17
arr.append(perimeter)
arr.append(area)
arr.append(radius)
```

Hope I could help.
If any problem please elaborate your question aand specify the task.

Comment: Since im integrating this into camera but with the print result, My question is if i take the first picture the result will be given then if i take another picture the results will be give though, then how do i add those 2 results?

Comment: It depends on what type of data you are trying to store. For generic data I've mentioned the method. Still I am not able to understand your problem clearly. Apologies.

Comment: example im storing a data an integer in my first take photo, then in 2nd take there will be results also after those two result have found those two will be add.